# Protobuf field name which contains word "Id" capitalize it to "ID" when generate .pb.swift model

Tags: swift, protocol-buffers, protoc

I'm trying to use swift-protobuf:

```
$ protoc --version
libprotoc 3.3.0
$ protoc-gen-swift --version
protoc-gen-swift 0.9.904
```

I have `Test.proto` file, which I need to convert to `Test.pb.swift`:

```
syntax = "proto2";

message Test {
   optional int64 TestId = 1 [default = 0];
}
```

To do this I'm using:

```
$ protoc --swift_opt=Visibility=Public  --swift_out=./ ./Test.proto
```

It generate's long .pb.swift file:

```
public struct Test: SwiftProtobuf.Message {
  public static let protoMessageName: String = "Test"

  public var testID: Int64 {
    get {return _testID ?? 0}
    set {_testID = newValue}
  }
  /// Returns true if `testID` has been explicitly set.
  ....
```

So, why `TestId` converted to `testID`, e.g. why `Id` capitalized to `ID`?
How to fix or avoid this capitalization behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Particular answer was founded in [apple/swift-protobuf](https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf) repo in [#491 Add "id" to the list of uppercase names](https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf/pull/491).

So as I understand, now I need rename all my 'id' or 'Id' usages to "ID".